# How can you set a lot of text to a property in code only without embedding as a resource?

Tags: c#, winforms

Suppose I wanted to directly set `myCustomHtmlPanel.Text` to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Top navbar example for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="navbar-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="collapse" id="navbar-header">
      <div class="container-fluid bg-inverse p-a-1">
        <h3>Collapsed content</h3>
        <p>Toggleable via the navbar brand.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded navbar-static-top m-b-1">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-header">
        &#9776;
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Navbar example</h1>
        <p class="lead">This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the top-aligned navbar works. As you scroll, this navbar remains in its original position and moves with the rest of the page.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Without embedding it as a resource, or doing stuff like :

```
myCustomHtmlPanel.Text =
"<!DOCTYPE html>"
+ "<html lang=\"en\">"
+ "  <head>"
+ "    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">"
+ "    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">"
+ "    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no\">"
+ "    <meta name=\"description\" content=\"\">"
+ "    <meta name=\"author\" content=\"\">"
+ "    <link rel=\"icon\" href=\"../../favicon.ico\">"
+ ""
+ "    <title>Top navbar example for Bootstrap</title>"
+ ""
+ "    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->"
+ "    <link href=\"../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">"
+ ""
+ "    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->"
+ "    <link href=\"navbar-top.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">"
+ "  </head>"
+ ""
+ "  <body>"
+ ""
+ "    <div class=\"collapse\" id=\"navbar-header\">"
+ "      <div class=\"container-fluid bg-inverse p-a-1\">"
+ "        <h3>Collapsed content</h3>"
+ "        <p>Toggleable via the navbar brand.</p>"
+ "      </div>"
+ "    </div>"
+ "    <div class=\"navbar navbar-light bg-faded navbar-static-top m-b-1\">"
+ "      <button class=\"navbar-toggler\" type=\"button\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-target=\"#navbar-header\">"
+ "        &#9776;"
+ "      </button>"
+ "    </div>"
+ ""
+ "    <div class=\"container\">"
+ "      <div class=\"jumbotron\">"
+ "        <h1>Navbar example</h1>"
+ "        <p class=\"lead\">This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the top-aligned navbar works. As you scroll, this navbar remains in its original position and moves with the rest of the page.</p>"
+ "        <a class=\"btn btn-lg btn-primary\" href=\"../../components/#navbar\" role=\"button\">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>"
+ "      </div>"
+ "    </div>"
+ ""
+ ""
+ "    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript"
+ "    ================================================== -->"
+ "    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->"
+ "    <script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js\" integrity=\"sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>"
+ "    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js\"><\/script>')</script>"
+ "    <script src=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js\" integrity=\"sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>"
+ "    <script src=\"../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js\"></script>"
+ "    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->"
+ "    <script src=\"../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js\"></script>"
+ "  </body>"
+ "</html>";
```

*which mangles the code with all sorts of escape values, and such*

Or other 'tricks' like :

- Saving as a resource, and loading from resources
- Loading from an external file / website / database

How can I embed a large block of text **as is** in my code for the purpose of setting it as a property value or other form of manipulation ?

In other languages, they have identifiers for direct inline inclusion while retaining/permitting the ability to work with the data from a variable. See [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx.  use `@" "` for a verbatim string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about a verbatim string literal.  If you put the @ symbol just before the opening quote, it'll allow line breaks and ignore escape characters.  You can still use double quotes by repeating the character twice.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I do not want to escape any quotations, and the @ symbol in the above context, does not work the way you intend.  eg `@"multi-line content here with quotes and other chars"`. Main thing, I would like to know what the equivalent of heredoc or nowdoc is in c#

Comment: Unfortunately, this may be the closest thing available in C# at the moment.  There have been suggestions to incorporate heredoc/nowdoc functionality now and again, but they haven't made their way up the list.  ( As recently as: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2649914-insert-heredoc-string-quoting-in-c )